# Getting TypeError based on whether I use a function or not

Tags: python, typeerror

I keep getting this error in my tic-tac-toe game: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)` for `%`: 
'`list'` and `'int'`".

I have a "turns" variable to count the number of turns that have passed, and have a list of strings that act as the board.

Given this code:

```
def x_or_o(t):
    """Check the number of turns for an even number and return a string."""
    if t % 2 == 0:
        return 'O'
    else:
        return 'X'

def place_char(i, t, brd):
    """Change the value of an item in the board list from an 'e' to an 'X' or
    'O'."""
    brd[int(i) - 1] = '{}'.format(x_or_o(t))

def turn(t, brd):
    """Read player input and print symbol onto the board."""
    print("Player {}'s turn.".format(x_or_o(t)))
    p_input = input('1-9: ')
    check_quit(p_input)
    if brd_empty(p_input, brd):
        place_char(p_input, brd, x_or_o(t))
        # brd[int(p_input) - 1] = '{}'.format(x_or_o(t))
    ...
```

When I use `place_char()` in the `if` statement in `turn()`, I get a `TypeError`. However, when I copy and paste the line from `place_char()` straight into`turn()`, my code runs fine.

Why do I get an error while using the function, but not while using the code from the function?

Comment: The error is raised, when `t` is a list. Your code does not show the origin of it's value.

Comment: The arguments are in the wrong order when you call the function with `place_char(p_input, brd, x_or_o(t))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def place_char(i, brd, xo):
    """Change the value of an item in the board list from an 'e' to an 'X' or
    'O'."""
    brd[int(i) - 1] = '{}'.format(xo)
```

can you try replacing your `place_char` method with this one.

Errors in your method:

- in your method signature `place_char(i, t, brd)` where the order is different
- you're calling `x_or_o` again with `t` inside `place_char` but you're already passing the the output of `x_or_o(t)` to  `place_char` method